# Hide animated element after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class over thumbnails called toolbar and I move it to the top on mouse over.

```
li .toolbar {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:24px;
    padding:0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition:top .3s;
    -moz-transition:top .3s;
    -o-transition:top .3s;
    transition:top .3s;
}

li:hover .toolbar{
    top:-20px;
}
```

So when I move it 20 pixels to the top I also want to hide it without using z-index.

Is there any way with jQuery or pure CSS to do this?
Thank you

Comment: If you want to hide it, what is the point of moving?

Comment: display: none or opacity: 0 will make it not visible

Comment: `visibility:hidden` -- `opacity:0` -- `height:0`

Comment: yes but it does it directly Im pushing to top via animation and I want to add these commands when it arrives to 20pixels I can do it with display:none too like that.

Comment: So I want to hide after 0.2 seconds or 0.3 as you see there is transition:top .3s;

Comment: just use transition delay on of theme

Comment: yes but how to do that?

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opacity to hide the toolbar and set transition delay to make it start after a specific time

see code snippet

```css
.li {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
}

.li .toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
  transition: top .3s .3s, opacity .3s;
}

.li:hover .toolbar {
  transition: top .3s, opacity .3s .3s;
  top: -20px;
  opacity: 0;

}
}
```

```html
<div class="li">
  <div class="toolbar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery animation chaining.

```
$('.toolbar').animate({top:-20},1000).animate({'z-index': 0},1000).animate({opacity:0});
```

So to clarify: Each animation is happening after the last animation finishes.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/233175/). You can see how z-index animation is working after the top animation and before opacity animation.